# Possible to report or remove comment from Android Play?

Tags: android

If someone posts an offensive comment on the Android Play comments section, is it possible to have it removed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can report the comment as "spam" from either the web interface (not the developer console) or from the Android client.

Comment: Seems strange that they don't really have a better way to do this, I had a look through the developer console too as thats where I expected it to be. Nonetheless, your answer seems to be the correct one, thanks for the help!

Comment: @NutterzUK were you able to have the comment removed after flagging it as spam? And also how long did it take?